# How we can divide row in 3 columns in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-core

I want to divide a row into 3 columns in a foreach loop using asp.net mvc core

**This is my code**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="h3">Products</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <div class="product-grid2">
                    <div class="product-image2">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="pic-1" src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/product-grid/demo3/images/img-2.jpeg">
                            <img class="pic-2" src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/product-grid/demo3/images/img-2.jpeg">
                        </a>
                        <ul class="social">
                            <li><a href="#" data-tip="Quick View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-tip="Add to Wishlist"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-tip="Add to Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a class="add-to-cart" href="">Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <h3 class="title"><a href="#">Women's Designer Top</a></h3>
                        <span class="price">$599.99</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here's the output

[image]

I would like to move that 2nd product into the  2nd column of the first row

Anu ideas?

Comment: Hi @A_Malik thank you for your question and welcome to SO, Can you please add the output of your code and why it's not working as you expect

Comment: Hello Thank you for your interest i have updated the output i am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your foreach loop is on the wrong line. You were creating multiple containers because the container itself was in the foreach loop, while I guess you only want the div with the products in there.

```
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="h3">Products</h3>
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                <div class="product-grid2">
                    <div class="product-image2">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="pic-1" src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/product-grid/demo3/images/img-2.jpeg">
                            <img class="pic-2" src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/product-grid/demo3/images/img-2.jpeg">
                        </a>
                        <ul class="social">
                            <li><a href="#" data-tip="Quick View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-tip="Add to Wishlist"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-tip="Add to Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a class="add-to-cart" href="">Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <h3 class="title"><a href="#">Women's Designer Top</a></h3>
                        <span class="price">$599.99</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

I do not know your browser requirements and the following is not a Razor template solution.

However, you might want to check out CSS grid and/or flexbox:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

It will give you a bunch more options when creating a responsive website.